# Printing path of spring.xml in classpath

Tags: java, spring

I am using the below code in my test class , to load all the spring.xml files in classpath and application-content.xml file.

```
@Override
protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
    return new String[] {
        "classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml", "application-context.xml"};
}
```

Is there a way to print path of all the "spring.xml" files in classpath? I have a number of jar files which have spring.xml in them. However some of these might not be required for running the tests. Is there a way to print them (jar files or path) and also remove the spring.xml files that are not required programattically?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Tichodrama.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(new DefaultResourceLoader());
Resource[] resources = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml");

for(Resource resource : resources) {
   System.out.println(resource.getDescription());
}
```

It's a bit underhand, and uses the non-public Spring API, but it should work for limited diagnostic purposes.