# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer fails to resolve property file under duplicate directory name - receive BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: java, spring, properties

## update

I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564301/43396) to print out the resulting java classpath from both "classpath:" and "classpath*:" and got the following, but I still get a BeanDefinitionStoreException from the PPC for a property defined in my jms.properties file. What gives!?

```
[main] INFO - .......Loading........
[main] INFO - printing normal classpath
[main] INFO - class path resource [conf/dev/jgroups.properties]
[main] INFO - printing wildcard classpath
[main] INFO - URL [jar:file:/filepath/StandaloneProject.jar!/conf/dev/jgroups.properties]
[main] INFO - URL [jar:file:/filepath/DependencyProject.jar!/conf/dev/jdbc.properties]
[main] INFO - URL [jar:file:/filepath/DependencyProject.jar!/conf/dev/jms.properties]
```

It works fine on my windows machine. It fails on my dev linux box??? Any help is appreciated, if you don't have an actual answer but can guide me how to debug what's happening, that helps too.

## update #2

I also tried adding

```
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
```

to my EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's property list, but I am still getting the BeanDefinitionStoreException :(

## background

I am working with a standalone java maven project that includes another project as a dependency. The included project is a core set of classes, and has properties files for each environment.

Those files are stored in main/resources/conf/[env] before being packed into the dependency jar (we'll call it DependencyProject). This project includes a Spring 2.5.6 PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to automatically load the properties into beans.

Now, what I'm trying to do is use jGroups to cluster my application across multiple servers. This requires adding env-specific properties files to StandaloneProject in addition to DependencyProject's properties, so jGroups knows which address and port it needs to communicate with in each environment. These properties don't belong in the dependency. I figure I'll put them in a config path under StandaloneProject with the same folder name, so as to be nice and consistent. Everyone likes consistency, right?

So, what I've got so far are folders that look like this:

> `DependencyProject/src/main/resources/conf/[env]`
>   (these folders contain files like jms.properties, jdbc.properties, etc.)

and

> `StandaloneProject/src/main/resources/conf/[env]`
>   (these folders contain a jgroups.properties file)

DependencyProject declares the following location in the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:

> `<value>classpath*:conf/${implementation.env}/*.properties</value>`

I do not intend to load the jGroups property file with Spring. I'm doing that the old fashioned way in my application execution.

## problem

The simple fact that there is a duplicate directory path of conf/[env] is causing a clash somewhere, and no properties from DependencyProject get loaded. I tried adding the "classpath*:" instead of just "classpath:", but it has no effect. I've also tried playing with IgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders, but I'm not sure that is the correct solution.

I know it has to do specifically with the folder structure, because I can insert a folder so that the two paths don't mirror each other, and everything works fine.

> `DependencyProject/src/main/resources/conf/[env]`
>   `StandaloneProject/src/main/resources/conf/folder/[env]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting a jgroups folder under my conf folder. I would have liked to have everything in the /conf directory instead of some properties in /conf and some in /conf/jgroups, but this works.