# How to correctly load context in Spring using web.xml and Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

i have a problem importing a Spring context in my servlet class. The methods are working fine in test (with context loaded). But i seem to be incapable of loading the context in my webapp. I'm using Tomcat 7. Here is my `web.xml` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>AgneseProva</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
    </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet> 
 <description></description>
 <display-name>Prova</display-name>
 <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>it.jenia.agnese.prova.Prova</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
 <description></description>
 <display-name>Presenze</display-name>
 <servlet-name>Presenze</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Prova</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Prova</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Presenze</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/Presenze</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

This is my application context `app-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
   <context:annotation-config />
    <import resource="classpath*:/test-prova-spring-configuration.xml" /> 
 </beans>
```

The file test-prova-spring-configuration.xml contains a series of import with the database configuration, the repository configuration, the entities and the services.

The Servlet class is:

```
 package it.jenia.agnese.prova;

 import it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository;
 import it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.PresenzaRepository;
 import it.jenia.vr.common.service.JspReporter;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

 public class Presenze extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Presenze.class);

 @Autowired
 CollaboratoreRepository collaboratoreRepository;
 @Autowired
 PresenzaRepository presenzaRepository;
 @Autowired
 JspReporter jsp;

 public Presenze() {
     super();
 }
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String messaggiojsp = "ok";
    String messaggiopr = "ok";
    String messaggiocr = "ok";
    if (jsp==null){
        messaggiojsp = "ko";
    }
    request.setAttribute("messaggiojsp", messaggiojsp);
    if(presenzaRepository ==null){
        messaggiopr = "ko";
    }
    request.setAttribute("messaggiopr", messaggiopr);
    if(collaboratoreRepository==null){
        messaggiocr = "ko";
    }
    request.setAttribute("messaggiocr", messaggiocr);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Presenze/presenze.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 }
```

The server doesn't throw any error, just like if the context was completely loaded, but the autowired fields are null in the servlet. So far i've tried:

1.Registering the servlet as a service with the @Service annotation and adding it's package to the component scan in the spring configuration file (test-prova-spring-configuration.xml)--> nothing changed, fields are null and Tomcat didn't trow any error.

2.Registering the servlet as a bean in the spring configuration file --> nothing changed, fields are null and Tomcat didn't trow any error.

3.Adding those three lines of code to the servlet:

```
public void init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this, config.getServletContext());
};
```

--> the pages throw an error (finally):

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze];

Traceback:

```
    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Presenze threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze.collaboratoreRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:110)
    it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze.init(Presenze.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze.collaboratoreRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:110)
    it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze.init(Presenze.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.jenia.ac.mail.rapportini.repository.CollaboratoreRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:110)
    it.jenia.agnese.prova.Presenze.init(Presenze.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, summarizing, the problem is that it cannot find the beans to autowire the repo in the servlet class.

I sort of finished my "newbie" resources so any help would be much appreciated..

PS. o i forgot I have a maven webapp, the dir structure is:

```
src
---main
------java
----------it.jenia.agnese.prova
---------------Presenze.java
------resources
------webapp
----------META-INF
--------------test-prova-spring-configuration.xml
--------------MANIFEST.MF
----------WEB-INF
--------------web.xml
--------------spring
------------------app-config.xml
----------Presenze
--------------presenze.jsp
```

Comment: The "no qualifying bean" in your stack print is usually just the last in a long line of issues with the spring beans config. Could you show the whole thing?

Comment: Edit done, but i solved the problem too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration files. I tried moving the META-IN directory around but without any success, then i changed this line:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/test-prova-spring-configuration.xml" />
```

to:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/test-prova-spring-configuration.xml" />
```

And suddenly the Server Tomcat gave me some output around some missing class for the configuration (they were included in my maven pom.xml but were tagged as test, as i was using the configuration just for test scope previously). When I toke off the test scope from the pom.xml every class was working fine. I just had to update the maven project and clean the tomcat project to get it to work. So it was a problem of the "classpath" not being recognized. The strange thing is that Tomcat didn't gave any output about the xml not being found. There should be a way to log the configuration loading process to fix that. I took some inspiration from the answer of this question [Printing path of spring.xml in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563692/printing-path-of-spring-xml-in-classpath) .